# event for runtime controls in c#

Tags: c#, events, runtime, controls

i try to make an controls in runtime (not one, "n" controls in runtime)
but now i want to create event for every single controls
i made one but it just work for the last control i create in runtime
how can i create event for every controls?

```
        private void CreateRuntimeControl(PictureBox pic)
    {
        lbl = new Label();
        number++;
        locationX = locationX + 20;
        locationY = locationY + 20;
        lbl.Name = number.ToString();
        lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 20);
        lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10 + locationX, 10 + locationY);
        lbl.Text = number.ToString();
        lbl.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        pic.Controls.Add(lbl);
        lbl.MouseDown += lbl_MouseDown;
    }
```

and event

```
        private void lbl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(lbl.Name);
    }
```

Best Regards

Comment: Try lbl.MouseDown += lbl_MouseDown;

Comment: what do you mean?   can you explain more, please?

Comment: You should not be instantiating a new EventHandler each time, instead just subscribe to the one you already have.

Comment: thats the code i wrote in top,  and when i add labels by click button every time and when i click them it just show me the last label not the label i clicked

Comment: In your event you reference only the last cteated label,look at noMad17's answer

Comment: looks to me like you're only calling the event `lbl_MouseDown` only once so how else do you expect it to do it for multiple times.. please edit your question and make it more clearer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your label. Do this `lbl.MouseDown += lbl_MouseDown;`
Then in your EventHandler:

```
MessageBox.Show(((Label)sender).Name);
```

To clarify; `sender` will be the object triggering the event so you need to cast it to Label and then you will be able to use its properties.

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer so that we know your problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What is `lbl` in your `lbl_MouseDown` method? If it's a class-wide member field which you use as a temporary storage for you just created label objects then you experience quite an expected behaviour. Use the `sender` argument of your method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) for this. It keeps your code nice and clean.

Like this:

```
var lbl = new Label();
lbl.MouseDown += (s,e) => this.HandleMouseDownOnLabel(lbl);

private void HandleMouseDownOnLabel(Label lbl)
{
    Messagabox.Show(lbl.Name);
}
```